# sync function call in Node

Tags: node.js

I think I have a little leak in understand the async sync workflow in node. I hope someone can tell me what is my leak or what I do wrong.

I have a basic function

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log("step 1");

    myOAuthLogic();

    console.log("step 2");
});
```

For myOAuthLogic I use a async function that call a promise:

```
function oauthPage(url) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.request({
            url: "/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials",
            method: "POST",
            baseURL: "https://xxx/",
            auth: {
                username: "xxx",
                password: "xxx"
            },
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: {
                "grant_type": "client_credentials",
                "scope": "user" 
            }
        }).then(res => {
            resolve(res.data.access_token);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response.status);
            resolve("");
        });
    });

}

async function myOAuthLogic() {
    try {
        const token = await oauthPage('https://xxx/')
        console.log(token);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('ERROR:');
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

What I expect is:

1. step 1
2. token
3. step 2

But what I get is

1. step 1
2. step 2
3. token

I thought that the async with await will cause the function to wait until ready. What I understand wrong here?

Comment: Your outer function *doesn't* await anything. Just marking a function async **does not** magically synchronise the rest of your code.

Comment: An `async` function always returns a promise so if the caller wants to wait for it's asynchronous operations to be done, the caller HAS to use `await` or `.then()` to know when `myAuthLogic()` is actually done.

Comment: Also, `axios.request()` already returns a promise.  Don't wrap it in an additional promise (that is considered an anti-pattern, likely to introduce programming errors).  Just return the promise axios already returns.

Comment: FYI, `resolve("")` when there's an error is a generally bad thing to do here.  Errors in promises should reject.  The caller should expect a resolved promise is success and errors are in rejections.  You can't chain promises properly when doing it the way you are showing.  If you just return the axios promise (like I already suggested) rather than wrap another promise around it, then you don't have this issue at all.  It will already reject just fine.

Answer (score 1):

use async/await for router function also.

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    try{
        console.log("step 1");
        await myOAuthLogic();
        console.log("step 2");
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

*Note:* no need to create new promise you can directly return `axios.request`.

```
function oauthPage(url) {
    return axios.request({
        url: "/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials",
        method: "POST",
        baseURL: "https://xxx/",
        auth: {
            username: "xxx",
            password: "xxx"
        },
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        data: {
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "scope": "user" 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that Express doesn't natively support promises (until 5.0 releases), so you should be very careful giving this advice to someone who is clearly inexperienced.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your suggestion I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - There's no issue at all making a request handler in Express 4.x be `async`.  Express will ignore the returned promise from the request handler, but as long as you don't rely on that in any way and catch your own errors, it's no problem at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 sure, but you're saying "there's no issue (except this issue)" and that's the one I'm talking about.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - This answer catches errors in the `async` function.  There is NO issue with the `async` request handler in this answer at all.  It's just silly to advise one not to use `async` in request handlers until Express 5.0.  That's like saying don't drive because you might get in an accident.  No, the advice is to drive carefully and safely, not to avoid driving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add async and await to treat your promise function:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {

console.log("step 1");

await myOAuthLogic();

console.log("step 2");
});
```